# Kotlin Coroutines. what is in charge of suspend function? how many thread could get involved when working with coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have a couple questions on kotlin coroutines.

1. **how many thread could get involved when working with coroutines?**
   if we use just Dispatchers.Main, would only one thread get involved(single threaded)? if we use Dispatchers.IO, would multiple thread possibly get involved (maximum of 64 threads)?
2. **what will be the use case for using Dispatchers.Main?** most articles that I have read say all UI related works should present in Dispatchers.Main and background related works(like reading/writing data from/to database, network requests) needs to present in Dispatchers.IO but I don't understand **what UI related works present in Dispatchers.Main since UI related work don't really necessary need coroutines (with Dispatchers.Main)**
3. we use susepnd fuction with coroutines for some works that could block the current thread. For example, read data from disk, network requests, or high tense computation etc. **if these works are executed by suspend function, what/who is in charge when these functions are suspended?** I think something has to be working on these suspend functions anyway. will that be background threads that is in charge of below?

- reading/writing data from/to databse
- waiting for network request
- computing high tense computation

please point out if my wording or questions are incorrect.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think you answered yourself. Short answer is: `Dispatchers.Main` - single thread, `Dispatchers.Default` - number of cores, `Dispatchers.IO` - at most 64. You can read about it [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/index.html). Full answer is a little more complicated as limits could be reconfigured, they may differ on different platforms (e.g. JavaScript is always single-threaded), `Default` partially shares threads with `IO`, etc. We can also create our own thread pools.
2. I'm not sure what do you mean. Coroutines are generally never necessary in order to do anything. But if we use coroutines inside UI application, then we should use `Dispatchers.Main` for UI-related stuff.
3. We should almost never use blocking code inside coroutines (one exception is `Dispatchers.IO`). If we do that, the coroutine won't suspend, but just block, possibly making other parts of our application unresponsive or degrading the performance.

Comment: for #2, when do I need to use Dispatchers.Main? could you provide me some code snippet as an example? because I use Dispatchers.IO to retreive data from network/database right away in a viewmodel without using Dispatchers.Main

Comment: for #3, yes I am retreiving data from network/database in Dispatchers.IO context. but what I am curious about is who/what is really in charge of waiting for that data while the suspend function is suspended? would background thread get involved at this moment to wait for the data?

Comment: #2 I'm not sure if you are aware, but normally in UI applications you can only modify UI-related stuff from the "main" thread. Try to add some view from the background thread and you will get an exception. For this reason UI frameworks often provide utils for "jumping" into the main thread. For example in Android we have `runOnUiThread()` function. Its suspending equivalent for using with coroutines is `Dispatchers.Main`.

Comment: #3 `Dispatchers.IO` manages a pool of threads that are meant for blocking. When you perform a blocking operation using `Dispatchers.IO`, you run your code inside one of these threads. You block it instead of some more critical thread.